# Using additional tables as lookup values in Access Query in IIF Statements?

Tags: ms-access

I'm currently working with an `Access(2010)` Query that is taking multiple order items and `GROUPING BY` the order number.  For example, a `customer` may have ordered `5` items under `order number 123` but my query groups all of these individual items into one line with each item in it's own column.  The objective is each individual order number is contained on one line because the query will be exported in a `.csv` format to 3rd party software.

Since I'm combining multiple records/items I'm running into issues when the description field is getting truncated based on `255` characters.  Since working in a query I don't see the option of changing the text field to a memo field, so that won't resolve the issue and the `GROUP BY` clause is capping all the text fields at `255` chars anyway.

So, my question is instead of using the description fields from the current query is there a way that I can use an additional table to lookup an items description based on the part number ordered?  Proposed new table would be something very simple like:

```
PART | DESC

123     Widget Z_Langs_AUS_INT<br>
567     Widget K_Langs_DOM_CAN<br>
890     Widget B_Langs_SM
```

So the ideal statement in the query would be something like `IIF TABLE1.PART#ORDERED(from current query) = NEWTABLE.PART(from new table)`, then obtain `NEWTABLE.DESC`(from new table) otherwise ""

This would return the description of a specific part number if the part number fields matched otherwise leave the field blank because it likely doesn't contain a part number.

I'd appreciate any suggestions at this point.  I may be going about this all wrong when trying to resolve this issue so fresh input is welcome.

Comment: Two quick questions:  Are you using the query table?  And Is this second table with `Part | Desc` already created?  Because you can run queries based on values from other tables to return values from a completely different table in the query table.  No vba needed if your tables already exist.

Comment: TKE...I'm currently pulling from another query because there are about 40 additional columns with expressions,etc...and the second table was created for the Part | Desc content just for testing. My tests were not working out so I ended up here ;)

Comment: Gotcha.  Well if the table is already created then make a query table, add the tables you want to pull from, and you can use `[Table1].[Part]` and `[Table2].[Part]` to compare same parts.  I can try and make an  example and post as an answer if you'd like.

Comment: TKE, A visual example may help.  I'd appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Don't write that as a query.  It's too complex to bother with, and is extremely simple to do with VBA and direct text access.  Add a reference to the **Microsoft Scripting Runtime** (scrun.dll), use internal query objects for your SQL data, and use code similar to what's below.

```
Sub makeText()
    Dim rs1 As Recordset, rs2 As Recordset
    Dim oFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject, oFile As Scripting.TextStream
    Dim txtLine As String

    Set oFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    oFile = oFSO.CreateTextFile("FileName.csv")

    Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("baseQuery")

    Do Until rs1.EOF
        txtLine = rs1!OrderNumber.Value

        Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("innerQuery")

        Do Until rs2.EOF
            txtLine = txtLine & "," & rs2!itemDesc.Value
            rs2.MoveNext
        Loop

        oFile.WriteLine txtLine

        rs1.MoveNext
    Loop

    oFile.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Doug...I have an additional 40 columns in my query plus the descriptions field...doesn't the approach above only take into account the text from the desc field/value or am I missing something here? My VBA is not exactly tip top so bear with me

Comment: As I read your description, each of those up-to 40 "columns" are really items attached to an order.  If you want more than one field per CSV column, you can go ahead and add additional `txtLine` entries on `rs2`'s inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a picture from an example database we used to use.  It has our parts with all the info you could need, and then the part that matches up with our vendor.  The query used will display each and every row where our part matches the vendor part.
[image]

You can also just put a [AskMeForMyPart] or whatever in square brackets like that to make the query pull based on that specific part.
[image][image]